# Swagger integration with play 2.6 java

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am developing a web application with play framework 2.6 and I want to use swagger for my API documentation but by play and other resource are provide the solution with scala, not with java. can anyone tell me how to use swagger with play-2.6 for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the situation as yours but I managed to solved mine using the steps listed in the [Swagger Github page.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/tree/master/play-2.6/swagger-play2).

The github repo recommend using

```
libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.6.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

but I used

```
libraryDependencies += "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.6.0"
```

Another useful link is: [Documenting play framework using swagger](https://sakthipriyan.com/2016/07/20/documenting-play-framework-using-swagger.html).